# install desktop on server

Tags: server, gui

Will the desktop be consuming resources if Im not using it?  If so, how do I turn it on/off?

Comment: FYI there's also text mode browsers which you can use without a GUI, such as lynx, maybe that's enough to configure those devices ?

Comment: It greatly depends on what your desktop is doing while idle (i.e. what besides the desktop is running).  Call `uptime` before installing the desktop. Then after installation and one hours later call `uptime` again. If you need more details what is using resources, install `atop` or `htop` to monitor your processes.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have a clean install of Ubuntu Server. The `apt` command is equivalent to `apt-get`. I've tested all myself (except the first one). If you want a remote desktop like vnc server, you will need at least 3,4,5 or 6. See more info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

1. Run GUI applications without GUI

   ```
   sudo apt install xauth
   ```

   Then any gui application that you install will also install the required dependencies. After you can connect with `ssh -X` command and run any gui application with X forwarding (never tried it with just xauth installed).
2. Minimal GUI:

   ```
   sudo apt install xorg
   sudo apt install openbox --no-install-recommends
   ```

   Run the command `startx` and openbox will start (you can open a terminal there and run any application you want)
3. Minimal GUI with display manager:

   ```
   sudo apt install xorg
   sudo apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter --no-install-recommends
   sudo apt install lightdm --no-install-recommends
   sudo apt install openbox --no-install-recommends
   ```

   After reboot you will see the lightdm login menu (I don't know how you can make it not to start automatically but I don't think it consumes too much resources when you haven't logged in). Maybe some themes won't appear correct, so if you don't mind more dependencies install all packages in the same order without the `--no-install-recommends` option.
4. A more functional minimal desktop environment (the one I use)

   ```
   sudo apt install xorg
   sudo apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter
   ```

   Install lightdm-gtk-greeter first or it will install unity-greeter as dependency:

   ```
   sudo apt install lightdm
   sudo apt install lxde-core
   sudo apt install lxpolkit #(pkexec can't run without it)
   sudo apt install lxsession-logout #(logout button doesn't work without it)
   ```
5. A full lightweight desktop environment

   ```
   sudo apt install lubuntu-core
   ```

   It will install all dependencies like xorg, ligthdm, alsa and many more things.
6. A bit heavier desktop environment

   ```
   sudo apt install xubuntu-core
   ```

   It will install all dependencies like xorg, ligthdm, alsa and many more things.

You can use the `--no-install-recommends` option at 5 and 6 but you may need to install additional packages for the full desktop experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can install desktop environments with `sudo apt --no-install-recommends install lubuntu-desktop`. This would be very lightweight

Thanks to Nick Weinberg from the comments: `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-core` should be better

Comment: `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-core` would be another,  even more lightweight option

Answer (score 0):

Two additional options you can use in SSH connection

Port forwarding

X11 Forwarding

Say a newly install application has a web administration interface that can only be accessed via localhost by default.  You can forward communications via ssh.

Additionally, you can install a web browser on the server and use x11 forwarding to transmit the application window display through ssh to the client.

Because x11 forwarding is transmitting images, it is usually slower than port forwarding.  Both can be useful tools depending on your situation.